# Using OOP to reduce code and make it reusable

Tags: javascript, oop, code-reuse

I am creating an application and I have a question about the way in which I go about making it.

- You will be able to choose a number which determines the passage of time in minutes for two identical circles. (Separate buttons are created for incrementing and decrementing time for each circle)
- As the time passes, the first circle fills up until the countdown for the first circle reaches 0 minutes.
- Now a second identical circle will start the countdown and to fill up also based on the initial time you had given to it.

I have linked all the appropriate DOM elements(the circle, the buttons for incrementing/decrementing time) to the functions and event handlers written for the first circle and it runs perfectly. The second circle is essentially the exact same thing, except that it has a different `button` element for it's events and of course it is a different circle.

If I copy and paste all my code and just change the variables and function names associated with circle 1 to new ones for circle 2 it would work perfectly. That seems very repetitive and I'm sure there is a better way to go about this.

What comes to my mind is OOP. So instead of saying circle1 OR circle2 should fill up when I press this button, I can just say THIS circle fills up, when I press THIS button associated with each circle. Am I right in my thinking ? Is OOP the answer to my question here?

Comment: I'm not sure this isn't too broad a question, but you seem on the right track. I'd recommend implementing it as you describe, then you can post to the codereview stackexchange for detailed feedback.

Comment: I added the code,please let me know how I can make this shorter using OOP.

Comment: Yeah, this is one for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Ok will post there then. thanks.

Comment: You're on the right track and if you use ECMAScript 6, you'll have a much easier JavaScript life. Google: `system.js` and `ES6`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get it to work with code duplication, that's a great start. What you  have to do then is called *refactoring*:

Look for parts of the code which are exactly repeated, and if possible extract them into one function.

Then look for the parts of the code where you are doing things like `var1` and `var2`, and think about ways to abstract that repetition in either a loop over an array, a generator function, or OOP class & instance patterns.

As you go along you will notice that your code will be functionally the same, but much easier to reason about and read.

Also don't be afraid of re-starting from a blank file!

Comment: I was thinking about re starting from a blank file actually, it's just too repetitive. I know this should work with OOJS, I'm just very new to OOP and would appreciate guidance in how to go about it.

Comment: _guidance in how to go about_ OOP? That is one for Google I believe. Searching things like "javascript `new` keyword", "javascript instances", "javascript prototype", etc. will progressively help form an understanding.

Comment: Reactive Programming is also something you could look into, as it is very suited for the sort of thing you describe. Look at [baconjs.github.io](https://baconjs.github.io/)